# How to fetch the values using inner join

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

[image]I have two tables, from that i need to fetch each row value, and print it like below.

```html
<table id="contact" class="display">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Business Email</td>
        <td>Mobile No</td>
        <td>Company Name</td>
        <td>Message</td>
        
       </tr>
      </thead> 
                           <tr>           
                            <td><?php echo $result['0']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $result['1']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $result['2']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $result['3']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $result['4']; ?></td>       
      </tr><?php 
      }
      ?>
     </table>
```

I have tried

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_value)
                                FROM  `table2` GROUP BY  `submit_time`
```

But it will make problem in explode step.
If comma separator came in message field, explode function increase array value, i cant fetch the correct value and print it. 
Kindly share the idea to fix this.

Comment: Whats is table 1 and 2? Is is actual table you are having? If these are the real table why cant you get rid of table 1? What about primary key?

Comment: tables generated by wordpress plugin, from that i need to fetch the value and print it. so i don't have way to rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a primary key or atleast an auto increment key on the first table in order to associate it with the second table. The plugin you are using might be using it by ordering it. So every table 2 entry has a table 1 entry ordered by timestamp. What you have to do is create a new table1 column called ID and make it auto increment, it wont effect the working of the plugin. Then you can use a custom query like this.

```
SELECT $wpdb->table1.*
    FROM $wpdb->table1
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->table2 ON ($wpdb->table1.ID = $wpdb->table2.ID)
    WHERE $wpdb->table2.field_name = 'text-506'
```